# Using tidyverse how to extract values from a column in dataframe based on values in another dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

Suppose I have 2 data frames:

```r
df1 = data.frame(
  x1 = c('A','B','C','D'),
  x2 = c('C','D','E','F'))

df2 = data.frame(x = unique(c(df1$x1,df1$x2)))
df2$index = seq(1,length(df2$x),by=1)
```

I want to extract index values corresponding to entries in a column in df1 from those in df2. For example, I want an output like:

```r
df1$x2_indices = c(3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: Try `df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c("x2" = "x"))` using the `dplyr` package.

Comment: will this work even if the lengths of columns x2 and x are different?

Comment: Yes, the join looks for a match independent of the length of the columns.